# Silverlight horizontal stretch and get position issue

Tags: silverlight, grid, position, alignment

I have a Grid (container) wich in turn has several grids(subContainers) arranged by rows. Each one of those "subContainers" has diferent columns and controls. And each of those "subContainers" has the horizontal alignment set to stretch, and it has to stay that way, since the layout this viewer depends on it.

I use the "container" to set each control on it's adequate position. So far so good. Now comes my headache... I want to remove the control from the grid and put it in a canvas, at the same exact position, only, the position it returns is as if the control is set to the beggining of the grid and not it's true position.
For testing purposes, I've set the "subContainters" horizontal alignment to center and (despite the layout is totally wrong) every control is in it's right position when sent to a canvas, wich it doesn't happen when HA = stretch.
Here's the code I'm using to get position:

```
GeneralTransform gt = nc.TransformToVisual(gridZoom);
Point offset = gt.Transform(new Point());
```

So you can understand, for example, my first control should be somewhere like (80, 1090), but the point that I get is (3,3).

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using the top level container (which contains all other subcontainers) to get the offset point.

Also you can try:

```
var transform = mySubSubSubElement.TransformToVisual(Application.Current.RootVisual);
var position = transform.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
```

Comment: What do you mean?? Do you mean this: "GeneralTransform gt = nc.TransformToVisual(Container);" ??? I've tried as well, with the same result, the offset return (3,3) :(

Comment: Then try (I've posted the same code above as well):

var transform = mySubSubSubElement.TransformToVisual(Application.Current.RootVisual);
var position = transform.Transform(new Point(0, 0));

Comment: Thanks. It worked almost perfect :P, the only thing, since the sub element is not on the (0,0) point in the control, I had to subtract the difference to the offset point and VOILA :DDD It looks GREAT Thanks a lot :D